# Why do I not see the Upload feature in Sharepoint online? I can see it if I switch to Classic view, but our users will be looking for 'Upload'

Tags: sharepoint-online

Why do I not see the Upload feature in Sharepoint online? I can see it if I switch to Classic view, but our users will be looking for 'Upload' tp add new documents to libraries and lists.

Comment: What buttons do you have in the command bar? Upload should certainly be there, right next to new...

Comment: + New    Export to Excel    Flow   ...

Comment: Then if I select a sub-folder, I see: +New   Share   Copy Link   Download   Export to Excel   Flow   ....

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, there is “Upload ” beside the “New” in the command bar as the picture below.

[image]

Did the issue occur in all document libraries? The “Upload” only occurs in document libraries.

In the list, it will display as the picture below:

[image]

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if the user has the proper permission in the document library.
2. Switch to other browser to check if the same issue will occur.
3. Create a new document library to check if the same issue will occur.